# Is there any way to rollback transactions in SSIS for SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, distributed-transactions, msdtc

Cannot successfully execute an SSIS package with `BEGIN TRAN` functionality.

I'm at a loss with an SSIS package I inherited. It contains:

- 1 Script Task
- 3 Execute SQL tasks
- 5 Data flow tasks (each contains a number of merges, lookups, data inserts and other transformations)
- 1 file system task of the package.

All of these are encapsulated in a Foreach loop container. I've been tasked with modifying the package so that if any of the steps within the control/data flow fails, the entire thing is rolled back. Now I've tried two different approaches to accomplish this:

I. Using Distributed Transactions.

I ensured that:

- MSDTC was running on target server and executing client (screenshot enclosed)
- msdtc.exe was added as an exception to server and client firewall
- Inbound and outbound rules were set for both server and client to allow DTC connections.
- ForeachLoop Container `TrasanctionLevel`: Required
- All other tasks `TransactionLevel`: Supported
- My OLEDB Connection has `RetainSameConnection` set to TRUE and I'm using SQL Server Authentication with Save Password checked

When I execute the package, it fails right after the script task (first step). 
After spending an entire week trying to figure out a workaround, I decided to try SQL Tasks to try to accomplish my goal using 3 Execute SQL Tasks:

- `BEGIN TRAN` before the ForeachLoop Container
- `COMMIT TRAN` after the ForeachLoop Container with a Success Constraint
- `ROLLBACK TRAN` after the ForeachLoop Container with a Failure constraint

In this case, the ForeachLoop container and all other tasks have `TransactionLevel` property set to `Supported`. Now here, the problem is that the package executes up to the fourth data flow task and hangs there forever. After logging into SQL Server and verifying the running sessions, I noticed `sys.sp_describe_first_result_set;1` as a headblocker session.

Doing some research, I found it could be related to a few `TRUNCATE` statements in some of my Data flow tasks which could cause a schema lock. I went ahead and changed the `ValidateExternalMetaData` property to False for all tasks within my data flow and changed my truncate statements to `DELETE` statements instead. Re-ran package and still hangs in the same spot with the same headblocker. As an alternative, I tried creating a second OLEDB connection to the same database, assigned that new OLEDB Connection to my `BEGIN`, `ROLLBACK` and `COMMIT` SQL tasks with `RetainSameConnectionProperty` set to TRUE and changed the `RetainSameConnectionProperty` to FALSE (and tried it with TRUE as well) in the original OLEDB connection (the one used by the data flow tasks). This worked in the sense that the package appeared to execute (It ran and Commit Tran executed fine) and then I ran it again with a forced error to cause it to fail and the `Rollback TRAN` task executed successfully, however, when I queried the affected tables, the transaction hadn't rolled back, all new records were inserted and old ones were updated (the `begin tran` was clearly started in a different connection and hence didn't affect the package's workflow). I'm not sure what else to try at this point. Any help would be truly appreciated, I’m about to go nuts with this!

P.S. additionally, all objects have "DelayValidation" set to true on everything and SQL Server version is 2012.

Comment: You don't normally start and commit transactions manually. You set all components' TransactionLevel to Supported, and at the package level you set TransactionLevel to Required. Then it will manage it itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply GSerg! Notice how that was the first thing I tried. I set the ForeachLoop Container to required and everything else to supported. Got the connection error I described above. I then tried to set the transaction Level to Required on the package level and supported on everything else, and still got the connection error as if there was something wrong with the DTC.

Comment: What exactly needs to be rolled back?  If it is just data modifications to a final/production database, could you not modify the package to work within a volatile staging area and then add a final `Execute SQL` task to merge the old and new data within a single database transaction?  That way, if the earlier steps fail, there is no modification to your prod data and you don't have to try and get Distributed Transactions working.

Comment: The first approach does not require `RetainSameConnection` set to TRUE. Please try it with FALSE setting.
On the latter question - having switched to MS native transactions with `BEGIN TRAN`, you have to ensure yourself that only one connection is used. Transaction will be in scope of the first connection, all other connections will not be covered by transaction. This answers why no proper rollback with `RetainSameConnectionProperty` to FALSE - multitude of connections etc.